# Traefik CORS Middleware not respecting accessControlAllowOriginList

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, traefik-middleware

I have created following middleware for API endpoint

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: cors-api
  namespace: api-staging
spec:
  headers:
    accessControlAllowMethods:
      - "GET"
      - "OPTIONS"
      - "PUT"
      - "POST"
      - "DELETE"
    accessControlAllowHeaders:
      - "*"
    accessControlAllowOriginList:
      - "https://*.example.com"
    accessControlMaxAge: 100
    addVaryHeader: true
```

& attached it to `IngressRoute`

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: api-external-0
  namespace: api-staging
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`api.staging.example.com`)
      services:
        - name: nginx
          port: 80
          strategy: RoundRobin
          sticky:
            cookie:
              httpOnly: true
      middlewares:
        - name: cors-api
          namespace: api-staging
  tls:
    secretName: staging-cert
```

But following request is going through

```
% curl -v --request OPTIONS 'https://api.staging.example.com' -H 'Origin: http://fake.origin.com' -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'
*   Trying x.x.x.x:443...
* Connected to api.staging.example.com (x.x.x.x) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.staging.example.com
*  start date: Jan 11 02:15:45 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 10 02:15:44 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.staging.example.com" matched cert's "*.staging.example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://api.staging.example.com/
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: OPTIONS]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: api.staging.example.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.4.0]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [origin: http://fake.origin.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [access-control-request-method: GET]
> OPTIONS / HTTP/2
> Host: api.staging.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://fake.origin.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
< HTTP/2 200
< access-control-allow-headers: *
< access-control-allow-methods: GET,OPTIONS,PUT,POST,DELETE
< access-control-max-age: 100
< content-length: 0
< date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 17:54:27 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host api.staging.example.com left intact
```

I also tried `accessControlAllowOriginListRegex` still no luck

```
spec:
  headers:
    accessControlAllowMethods:
      - "GET"
      - "OPTIONS"
      - "PUT"
      - "POST"
      - "DELETE"
    accessControlAllowHeaders:
      - "*"
    accessControlAllowOriginListRegex:
      - "(.*?)\\.example\\.com"
    accessControlMaxAge: 100
    addVaryHeader: true
```

I am expecting, once the CORS policy are in place, curl request with non `accessControlAllowOriginListRegex` will be refused.

Any thoughts on what is happening here ?

Answer (score 0):

Never used Traefik, but I googled `accessControlAllowOriginList` and [the documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/headers/#accesscontrolalloworiginlist) strongly suggests that the asterisk is only allowed by itself to match any origin, but not in the middle of a origin.

It also appears a second `accessControlAllowOriginListRegex` setting is available to set up patterns.

Comment: I tried `accessControlAllowOriginListRegex` but still no luck

Comment: @rp346 your regex doesn't look like a valid value for an origin. An origin is not just a domain, it should include a schema.

Comment: What would be the correct way do it ?

Comment: @rp346 I would suggest you take some valid origins you want to support, and use a regex testing tool to see if they match. Works better than guessing! Then double the backslashes for escaping and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Traefik documentation is notoriously vague on how to actually use the configuration options. Luckily, we can learn something from its source code.
In [these](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/master/pkg/middlewares/headers/header_test.go#L282://) unit tests there are some examples of accessControlAllowOriginListRegex usage, and according to them your regex should be formatted like this:

```
    accessControlAllowOriginListRegex:
      - "^(.+)\\.example\\.com$"
```

these are other examples of valid regex:

```
"^https?://([a-z]+)\\.bar\\.org$"
"([a-z]+)\\.bar"
```

From a quick glance at the [source code](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/master/pkg/middlewares/headers/header.go#L177) instead it's clear that wildcards are not supported in `accessControlAllowOriginList`

Comment: I tried `- "^(.+)\\.example\\.com$"` , `"^https?://([a-z]+)\\.example\\.com$"` but still unable get the desired result